# Finding integer closest to value of given expression

Tags: fractions

> Find the integer which is closest to the value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{5^6+1}-\sqrt[6]{5^6-1}}$

How do you do this? I try to rationalize but that gets to $\frac{\sqrt[6]{5^6+1}+\sqrt[6]{5^6-1}}{\sqrt[3]{5^6+1}-\sqrt[3]{5^6-1}}$ and I really don't know where to proceed from here.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: ?? The denominator of your "value" is zero. Typo?

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. Already edited

Comment: The top of rationalized form is very near $10$ and if you at this point use the difference of cuberoots for the bottom it becomes about $3 \cdot 5^5,$ which seems to  be the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution: Remember:
$$x^{n + 1} - y^{n + 1} = (x - y) (x^n + x^{n - 1} y + \dotsb + x y^{n - 1} + y^n)$$
use this to rationalize. You get rid of the roots in the denominator, the numerator is a sum of roots, which you'd have to handle next.

But next to $5^6$, 1 is small, check if they make a difference (now you have a sum, easier to handle than the original fraction).

Or you could expand as:

$\begin{align*}
   \frac{1}
            {\sqrt[6]{5^6+1}
                \left(
                    1 - \sqrt[6]{(5^6 - 1) / (5^6 + 1)}
              \right)}
\end{align*}$

This is just a geometric series, but it looks like the ratio is very near one, so it'll converge slowly, perhaps too slow to get an estimate within 1/2 with a reasonable number of terms.